# model.predict yeilds more predictions than the number of outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I've created a multi-class image classifier using CNN. I am using the `keras` module specifically and I am using generators to fit and then predict 4 different classes of images. My `test_generator` has 394 examples (all four classes combined), but my model.predict yields (6304, 4) predictions.

Here's the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 IP (Conv2D)                 (None, 64, 64, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 Convolution0 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 64, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 PL0 (MaxPooling2D)          (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 Convolution1 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 32, 128)       73856     
                                                                 
 PL1 (MaxPooling2D)          (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 Convolution2 (Conv2D)       (None, 16, 16, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 PL2 (MaxPooling2D)          (None, 8, 8, 256)         0         
                                                                 
 FL (Flatten)                (None, 16384)             0         
                                                                 
 FC (Dense)                  (None, 128)               2097280   
                                                                 
 OP (Dense)                  (None, 4)                 516       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2,485,636
Trainable params: 2,485,636
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here's how I created the test_generator:
`test_generator = core_imageDataGenerator(test_directory)` and the result of
`len(test_generator.classes)` is 394.

Here's how I made the predictions:
`predictions = model.predict(test_generator)` and the result of `predictions.shape` is [6304, 4] and not [394, 4]. What could be the reason for this? Am I doing something wrong? What are my options here because my next step is to create a classification report with a variety of metrics.

Comment: are you using a batch size of 16? It is likely you are confusing samples with steps in a generator.

Answer (score 0):

that is input and number of layers I see you use the flatten layer followed by dense matrix, which indicates the output matrix of layers.

There are convolution layers and dense layers, 320 -> 18496 ( 32 * 578 ) -> MaxPool which return the same sizes.

You may create an engine similar to the attached picture, the output is sensitive your problems are similarities and ratios. ( 6304, 4 ) , ( 394, 4 ).

They are important in statistics methods, **simply mean you do not need much of dense layers we had do it for you !!!**

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def predict_action ( dataset ) :
    predictions = model.predict( dataset )
    return predictions

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
input = tf.constant( tf.random.uniform(shape=[5, 2], minval=5, maxval=10, dtype=tf.int64), shape=( 1, 1, 5, 2 ) )
label = tf.constant( [0], shape=( 1, 1, 1 )  )
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( input, label ))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 5, 2 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense( 4 ),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense( 128 ),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense( 4 ),
])  
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1 ,validation_data=(dataset))
print( predict_action( dataset ) )
```

**[ Output ]:**

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 5, 4)              12

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 20)                0

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 16)                336

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 68

=================================================================
Total params: 416
Trainable params: 416
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step - loss: 0.2335 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2291 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
[[ 0.07219216 -2.9527428   1.5981569  -5.590222  ]]
```

Comment: You are not actually answering the question.

Comment: This did not help at all. I reckon the data sample is just a dummy to show case your model. I don't think that optimizers and loss functions have anything to do with the issue I'm facing. As per your suggestion I tired removing the Dense layer below the flattened layer but no changes. Thanks for your time tough!

Comment: I examined the layer output and input relation if you read about my answer.

There are convolution layers and dense layers, 320 -> 18496 ( 32 * 578 ) -> MaxPool which return the same sizes.

You may create an engine similar to the attached picture, the output is sensitive your problems are similarities and ratios. ( 6304, 4 ) , ( 394, 4 ).

They are important in statistics methods, simply mean you do not need much of dense layers we had do it for you !!!
How much Maxpool reutn ratios and CONV return ratios?